# Extract raw data from Tables in Word? using Perl

Tags: perl, ms-word, automation, win32ole

I'm trying to extract data from multiple **Tables** in a Word document. When trying to convert the data in the tables to text I get an error. The **ConvertToText** method has two optional parameters(how to seperate the data, and a boolean).Here is my current code:

```
#usr/bin/perl
#OLEWord.pl

#Use string and print warnings
use strict;use warnings;
#Using OLE + OLE constants for Variants and OLE enumeration for Enumerations
use Win32::OLE qw(in);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

my $var1 = Win32::OLE::Variant->new(VT_BOOL, 'true');

$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

#set the file to be opened
my $file = 'C:\work\SCL_International Financial New Fund Setup Questionnaire V1.6.docx';

#Create a new instance of Win32::OLE for the Word application, die if could not open the application
my $MSWord = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') or Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application','Quit');

#Set the screen to Visible, so that you can see what is going on
$MSWord->{'Visible'} = 1;
 $MSWord->{'DisplayAlerts'} = 0; #Supress Alerts, such as 'Save As....'

#open the request file or die and print warning message
my $Doc = $MSWord->{'Documents'}->Open($file) or die "Could not open ", $file, " Error:", Win32::OLE->LastError();

#$MSWord->ActiveDocument->SaveAs({Filename => 'AlteredTest.docx', 
                            #FileFormat => wdFormatDocument});

my $tables = $MSWord->ActiveDocument->{'Tables'};

for my $table (in $tables){
   my $tableText = $table->ConverToText(wdSeparateByParagraphs,$var1);
   print "Table: ", $tableText, "\n";
}


$MSWord->ActiveDocument->Close;
$MSWord->Quit;
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Bareword "VT_BOOL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at OLEWord.pl line 31
>   Bareword "true" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at OLEWord.pl line 31
>   Execution of OLEWord.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When things like `VT_BOOL` are not defined as constant, perl will consider them bareword. Others already provided info on them.

The root cause of your problem are missing constants that are exported by [Win32::OLE::Variant](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE%3a%3aVariant) module. Add:

```
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
```

to your script to remove first error. The second one is similar problem, `true` is not defined as well. Replace it with `1` or define constant yourself with:

```
use constant true => 1;
```

**Edit:** Here is example of extracting table text:

```
my $tables = $MSWord->ActiveDocument->{'Tables'};
for my $table (in $tables){
   my $tableText = $table->ConvertToText({ Separator => wdSeparateByTabs });
   print "Table: ", $tableText->Text(), "\n";
}
```

In your code you had typo in method name `ConverToText`. Also the method returns `Range` object, so you have to use `Text` method to get actual text.

Comment: Yes I forgot about that thanks, but what about extracting data from tables in Word>

Comment: @Shahab - please see my updated answer for table extraction code.

Comment: hmmm, i got an error running: OLE exception from "Microsoft Word" This method or property is not available because some or all of the data does not refere to a table -> at ConverToText.

Comment: I though the Tables property returned a collection of the Tables in the document?

Comment: @Shahab - you are right, `Tables` is collection, you iterate with `in` over it and each one convert to text. Did you notice the missing `t` in `ConverToText`?

Comment: @Shahab - yes it does. I made a simple document with just one table though, but data are printed nicely. What error are you getting and on what line?

Comment: line 27, so where I am initiating the MSWord variable

Comment: @Shahab - this is weird. I probably cannot help much with the debugging on your side. Here is [full source code I used](https://raw.github.com/bvr/experiments/6eb95575473dd3134a7c95f70e9cbbe584b56920/scripts/2011-07-18-ole-word.pl). Hope that helps.

Comment: ya there must be an issue on my computer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

> A 'Bareword' error is caused by a syntax error in your code. A
>   'runaway multi-line' usually pinpoints where the start of the error
>   is, and usually means that a line has not been completed, often
>   because of mismatched brackets or quote marks.
>
> As has been pointed out by several SO-ers, that doesn't look like
>   Perl! The Perl interpreter is balking on a syntax error because it
>   doesn't speak that particular language! [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833203/bareword-found-where-operator-expected/4849808#4849808)

Not using strict will not give you the warning. (But you should use it for a good code)

Read about Bareword so that you will know what are they and you will know by your own that how can you correct this error.

Here are some links for study about Bareword:
1. [perl.com](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/01/begperl6.html)
2. [alumnus](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~svhwan/prodScript/avoidBarewords.html#sec2)

Comment: thanks, what about how to extract data from tables? Does the code seems correct?

Answer (score 1):

removing "use strict"  will remove the "Bareword" errors

Answer (score 0):

extract all the doc tables into a single xls file

```
     sub doParseDoc {

           my $msg     = '' ; 
           my $ret     = 1 ; # assume failure at the beginning ...

           $msg        = 'START --- doParseDoc' ; 
           $objLogger->LogDebugMsg( $msg );
           $msg        = 'using the following DocFile: "' . $DocFile . '"' ; 
           $objLogger->LogInfoMsg( $msg );
           #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
           #Using OLE + OLE constants for Variants and OLE enumeration for Enumerations


           # Create a new Excel workbook
           my $objWorkBook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("$DocFile" . '.xls');

           # Add a worksheet
           my $objWorkSheet = $objWorkBook->add_worksheet();


           my $var1 = Win32::OLE::Variant->new(VT_BOOL, 'true');

           Win32::OLE->Option(Warn => \&Carp::croak);
           use constant true => 0;

           # at this point you should have the Word application opened in UI with t
           # the DocFile
           # build the MS Word object during run-time 
           my $objMSWord = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
                             or Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', 'Quit');  

           # build the doc object during run-time 
           my $objDoc   = $objMSWord->Documents->Open($DocFile)
                 or die "Could not open ", $DocFile, " Error:", Win32::OLE->LastError();

           #Set the screen to Visible, so that you can see what is going on
           $objMSWord->{'Visible'} = 1;
           # try NOT printing directly to the file


            #$objMSWord->ActiveDocument->SaveAs({Filename => 'AlteredTest.docx', 
                                        #FileFormat => wdFormatDocument});

           my $tables        = $objMSWord->ActiveDocument->Tables();
           my $tableText     = '' ;   
           my $xlsRow        = 1 ; 

           for my $table (in $tables){
              # extract the table text as a single string
              #$tableText = $table->ConvertToText({ Separator => 'wdSeparateByTabs' });
              # cheated those properties from here: 
              # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149(v=office.11).aspx#officewordautomatingtablesdata_populateatablewithdata
              my $RowsCount = $table->{'Rows'}->{'Count'} ; 
              my $ColsCount = $table->{'Columns'}->{'Count'} ; 

              # disgard the tables having different than 5 columns count
              next unless ( $ColsCount == 5 ) ;

              $msg           = "Rows Count: $RowsCount " ; 
              $msg           .= "Cols Count: $ColsCount " ; 
              $objLogger->LogDebugMsg ( $msg ) ; 

              #my $tableRange = $table->ConvertToText({ Separator => '##' });
              # OBS !!! simple print WILL print to your doc file use Select ?!
              #$objLogger->LogDebugMsg ( $tableRange . "\n" );
              # skip the header row
              foreach my $row ( 0..$RowsCount ) {
                 foreach my $col (0..$ColsCount) {

                    # nope ... $table->cell($row,$col)->->{'WrapText'} = 1 ; 
                    # nope $table->cell($row,$col)->{'WordWrap'} = 1  ;
                    # so so $table->cell($row,$col)->WordWrap() ; 

                    my $txt = ''; 
                    # well some 1% of the values are so nasty that we really give up on them ... 
                    eval {
                       $txt = $table->cell($row,$col)->range->{'Text'}; 
                       #replace all the ctrl chars by space
                       $txt =~ s/\r/ /g   ; 
                       $txt =~ s/[^\040-\176]/ /g  ; 
                       # perform some cleansing - ColName<primary key>=> ColName
                       #$txt =~ s#^(.[a-zA-Z_0-9]*)(\<.*)#$1#g ; 

                       # this will most probably brake your cmd ... 
                       # $objLogger->LogDebugMsg ( "row: $row , col: $col with txt: $txt \n" ) ; 
                    } or $txt = 'N/A' ; 

                    # Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column notation.
                    $objWorkSheet->write($xlsRow, $col, $txt);

                 } #eof foreach col

                 # we just want to dump all the tables into the one sheet
                 $xlsRow++ ; 
               } #eof foreach row
               sleep 1 ; 
           }  #eof foreach table

           # close the opened in the UI document
           $objMSWord->ActiveDocument->Close;

           # OBS !!! now we are able to print 
           $objLogger->LogDebugMsg ( $tableText . "\n" );

           # exit the whole Word application
           $objMSWord->Quit;

           return ( $ret , $msg ) ; 
     }
     #eof sub doParseDoc
```